# aspnet/signalr: Error parsing handshake response: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am trying to connect to signal R hub using javascript client. Seems I am able to connect but immediatly got disconnected.

Somes Logs:

> 2020-03-11T11:43:47.974Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
>   Utils.js:209 [2020-03-11T11:43:47.978Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
>   home.component.ts:115 Error establishing connection to signal r  Error: Error parsing handshake response: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
>       at HubConnection.push../node_modules/@aspnet/signalr/dist/esm/HubConnection.js.HubConnection.processHandshakeResponse (HubConnection.js:372)
>       at HubConnection.push../node_modules/@aspnet/signalr/dist/esm/HubConnection.js.HubConnection.processIncomingData (HubConnection.js:322)
>       at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (HubConnection.js:65)
>       at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYmessage] (WebSocketTransport.js:107)
>       at WebSocket.wrapFn (zone-evergreen.js:1191)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30885)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)

[image: Error Image]

I am getting the above error when connecting to SinalR hub. Below is my client code:

```js
this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('http://localhost:5000/signalr', {
    accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
  .build();

this.hubConnection
  .start()
  .then( () => console.log(this.hubConnection.state))
  .catch( error => console.log('Error establishing connection to signal r ', error));

 this.hubConnection.on('TotalTrucks', trucks => {
  console.log('HERE = ', trucks);
  this.tucks = trucks;
});
```

Note that I have a Background service sending messages to all connected clients every 1 minute:

```cs
public class OtcWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<OtcHub> _hubContext;
    private IServiceScopeFactory ServiceScopeFactory { get; set; }

    public OtcWorker(IHubContext<OtcHub> hubContext, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        ServiceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;

    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = ServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<WeighbridgeDataContext>();

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var result = await context.ReceiptTransactions.ToListAsync();

                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("TotalTrucks", result.Count);

                await Task.Delay(3600, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What SignalR client package are you using?

Comment: I am using @aspnet/signalr from NPM

Comment: That package is now obsolete. Try with ```@microsoft/signalr```. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-signalr-client-package

Comment: Even with @microsoft/signalr is giving me the same exact error.

Comment: You can look at this SignalR demo that implements a worker that sends also data to all clients. https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo

Comment: @Kiril1512, I have the same issue. I had a look at your SignalR demo but yours is using the aspnet package and not the latest one (microsoft).

Comment: You just need to change the `import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";` to `import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";` and install the package via npm.

Comment: @AndreiPetrut just updated my Github code to use new package.

Comment: @abdul.badru can you share the code to your hub and the server startup?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a polyfill that looks like `var Buffer = Buffer || [];`?
If so, remove that line of code.

If your index.html that has a `<script>` which contains
`var Buffer = Buffer || [];`
then remove that line of code.
this causes a handshake error with SignalR

Answer (score 0):

the method handshaking is waiting for a record separator

```
var textData = data;
var separatorIndex = textData.indexOf(TextMessageFormat.RecordSeparator);
if (separatorIndex === -1) {
throw new Error("Message is incomplete.");
}

TextMessageFormat.RecordSeparator = 0x1e;
```

if response is missing that separator, will generare an Error. "Error parsing handshake response: Error: Message is incomplete."